# DOM Parser dynamic id

Tags: php, dom

id-any number

```
<div id="news-id-1" style="display:inline;"></div>
<div id="news-id-31" style="display:inline;"></div>
<div id="news-id-320" style="display:inline;"></div>
```

How to make that work? (google translate)

> ```
> foreach ($html->find('div[id=news-id-?????]', 0)  as $e2) {     
>         echo $e2;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html->find("div[id^='news-id-']", 0)
```

should work.